# Assignment FOREIGN KEY in MYSQL 5.6.41 on mac os

Tags: mysql, macos

Face a problem while creating a table. I used the following queries:

```html
CREATE TABLE users ( 
id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,     
address_id int NOT NULL,     
first_name VARCHAR(40),     
last_name VARCHAR(40),     
age int,     FOREIGN KEY FK_address (address_id) REFERENCES address (id)
);
```

or

```html
CREATE TABLE Users (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);
```

each time I've caught error

*ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'KEY (address_id) REFERENCES address (id)*

I even tried to make a table and Assign key after

```html
CREATE TABLE Users (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
);

ALTER TABLE users ADD FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID);
```

but there was *ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'address_id' doesn't exist in the table*

Can anyone help me with a solution or any pieces of advice where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

create table address(
 add_Id number primary key);

CREATE TABLE users ( 
id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
address_id int NOT NULL, 
first_name VARCHAR(40), 
last_name VARCHAR(40), 
age int,      CONSTRAINT FK_address FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES address (add_id)
);

Comment: still error:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, address_id int NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR' at line 1

Comment: Yeah THANK YOU!

Comment: Welcome Brother!